# delete a selected row from jtable and data base (MySql)

Tags: java

im trying to delete a selected row from the jtable and the same row from the database, but my code can only delete from the jtable not from the database! 
here it is .

```
 stmt = con.createStatement();
                int row = DocsList.getSelectedRow();
                stmt.execute("DELETE FROM referencedocument WHERE title ="+row+"");  
              DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel)DocsList.getModel();
                int modelRow = DocsList.convertRowIndexToModel( row );
                  model.removeRow( modelRow );
```

Comment: Better use [Prepared Statements](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html).

Comment: i tried prepared statment, it didt work "(

Comment: Is `title` also an Integer in the database? It seems like it stores a name.

Comment: about that yah the type of title is string >_< but i dunt know how to deal with that

Comment: You need a distinct value which is present in the database and in your JTable, and create a query with this value. Since we don't know how your data-structure looks like is it hard to help you.

Comment: i have a primary key in my referenceDocument table called documentid but i dont want to show it in the jtable as well coz its for me not for my users of the program to see it so that's why i choos title but its string

Comment: Does this match with `row`?

Comment: When you store `documentId` in the JTable for example in the first column you can get it with `DocsList.getValueAt(row, 0);`

Comment: IT WORKS !! IT WORKS, thank you thank you Very much :")